# Not found Class 'Jenssegers\Agent\Agent' not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I have tried many times to install laravel on ubuntu 18.04. but there is a error showed in terminal. Please help me how to solve this.

> ```
> user@user:/opt/lampp/htdocs/project$ php artisan serve
>
> In constants.php line 4:
>
> Class 'Jenssegers\Agent\Agent' not found
> ```

Answer (score 0):

## Autoloading

You have to be sure, that your autoloading file is up to date.

Also, be sure that all packages from your composer.json are installed currently.

`composer install` will take care of both.

## Wrong class name

If you have checked the above the issue could be, that the autoloader is looking for a class name, that doesn't exists due to discrepancy between the *filename* and *classname*. E.g. you called the file "UserAgent.php", but the class name inside the file is "Agent".

Answer (score 0):

you can run **composer install** to fix the error. it works for me.

Comment: How this answer is different from the one written by @xyz ?

Comment: there is no need to autoload file, and the error might be as a result of someone added an import that is not in one class path after you do a git pull (as my own case), so having seen such scenario, just run "composer install" to pull such import to your local class path.

Answer (score 0):

try to execute
or

```
composer require install
```

or

```
composer require jenssegers/agent
```